# Maven dependency scopes - Revisited

Tags: maven

please does anybody know the answer to the following, rather obvious, question regarding the "matrix of scopes" in the official maven docs:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

The footnote explains why the cell indexed [compile,compile] again contains the value "compile".

In my opinion, the VERY SAME ARGUMENT implies the following:

1. Cells [compile,provided] and [provided,provided] both should contain "provided".
2. Cell [test,provided] should contain "test".

So why do all of these cells contain "-" ?!? 
It doesn't make sense to me...

Many thanks in advance for all kind of useful suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

`provided` means that the depedency is provided by the container, which implies that the usage of this scope depends on the container at hand.

Therefore, this scope should be set at the level of the "deployable unit" (war, ear, standalone jar), not somewhere deep down in the transitive dependency tree.
Hence it is not useful to have transitivity for `provided` dependencies.

Instead you can overwrite the scope with dependencyManagement at the highest level to ensure that you mark those dependencies as provided that are provided by your container.

Comment: Thanks,but I'm not convinced, sorry:

Consider the following situation:

1. "Container-Artefact" B depends on "Container-Artefact" C 
(scope "provided", why not...)
2. "My-Artefact" A depends on "Container-Artefact" B 
(scope provided, of course...)
3. A contains a class X extending a class Y in B.
4. Y extends a class Z in C.
5. X calls a protected method Z.m defined in Z

Now the compiler needs the definition of this class Z in order to check the signature of Z.m, for instance.
But due to to the "-" in the [provided,provided]-cell, class Z is not at hand and an error will occur.

Comment: I would see it this way: Either B is a "library" and should be used as a dependency - then it should not have provided dependencies because libraries can be used in different containers (or without any container). Or B is a deployable unit, like a war, ear, exectutable jar. Then it should define the necessary provided dependencies, but nobody (including your artefact A) should use it as dependency.